# How does abstergo score work in AC III multiplayer?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I have won some games and lost only a few games. However, for some reason my score went from 2350 to 1350 in two days. I do sometimes quit but I don't think that explains such a significant drop.

Why have I lost so many points?

How is Abstergo score determined?

Comment: I've explained in detail my understanding of the whole Abstergo Ladder on the UBI forums [here](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/738358-can-we-have-some-kind-of-official-response-regarding-ladder?p=8799794&viewfull=1#post8799794).  It's pretty complicated and I've learned a bit more since I wrote it. I don't know if I'm willing to rewrite the answer here so you can use it as reference.  But what likely happened was that you disconnected from a lot of games where you joined within the first 2 minutes of the match.

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to lose abstergo score but if you don't play for a while, you may lose a few points.

Quitting a game has nothing to do with losing points.

You can only lose points the other way by losing matches and you can gain points by winning matches.

And you state in your link that you mostly only get 10 points per win. This is wrong. The higher the "domination" of the win, the more points you get.

For example, if you dominate all points in a domination match and win straight away in 2 minutes from the start (Doesn't exactly take 2 minutes to win, this is just an example), it gives you a massive boost of about 50-90 score.

However, if you lose a match and you get "dominated", you lose a lot of score. For me, the most I have lost in a match is 150 points.